# How can I sort data before group data by specific field in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, sqlyog

My query like this :

```
SELECT a.id, a.store_id, a.name, a.total_sold, a.updated_at, b.name AS store_name
FROM products a
JOIN stores b ON b.id = a.store_id
JOIN products_categories c ON c.product_id = a.id
WHERE a.status = 1 AND a.stock > 0 AND c.category_id = 4
```

If the query executed, the result like this :

```
+----+----------+------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
| id | store_id | name       | total_sold | updated_at          | store_name |
+----+----------+------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
|  1 |        1 | product 1  |          1 | 2017-07-11 05:53:41 | store 1    |
|  2 |        1 | product 2  |          2 | 2017-07-11 06:53:41 | store 1    |
|  3 |        1 | product 3  |          3 | 2017-07-11 07:53:41 | store 1    |
|  4 |        2 | product 4  |          4 | 2017-07-11 08:53:41 | store 2    |
|  5 |        2 | product 5  |          5 | 2017-07-11 09:53:41 | store 2    |
|  6 |        3 | product 6  |          6 | 2017-07-11 10:53:41 | store 3    |
|  7 |        3 | product 7  |          7 | 2017-07-11 11:53:41 | store 3    |
|  8 |        3 | product 8  |          8 | 2017-07-11 12:53:41 | store 3    |
|  9 |        4 | product 9  |          9 | 2017-07-11 13:53:41 | store 4    |
| 10 |        5 | product 10 |          0 | 2017-07-11 14:53:41 | store 5    |
| 11 |        6 | product 11 |          1 | 2017-07-11 15:53:41 | store 6    |
| 12 |        7 | product 12 |          2 | 2017-07-11 16:53:41 | store 7    |
| 13 |        8 | product 13 |          3 | 2017-07-11 17:53:41 | store 8    |
| 14 |        8 | product 14 |          4 | 2017-07-11 18:53:41 | store 8    |
| 15 |        2 | product 15 |          5 | 2017-07-11 19:53:41 | store 2    |
| 16 |        2 | product 16 |          6 | 2017-07-11 20:53:41 | store 2    |
| 17 |        3 | product 17 |          7 | 2017-07-11 21:53:41 | store 3    |
+----+----------+------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
```

I want the data to be grouped by store_id and take the most total_sold and the latest updated_at

I try like this :

```
SELECT a.id, a.store_id, a.name, a.total_sold, a.updated_at, b.name AS store_name
FROM products a
JOIN stores b ON b.id = a.store_id
JOIN products_categories c ON c.product_id = a.id
WHERE a.status = 1 AND a.stock > 0 AND c.category_id = 4 AND 
       a.id = (SELECT e.id
           FROM products e
           JOIN stores b ON b.id = e.store_id
           JOIN products_categories c ON c.product_id = e.id
           WHERE e.status = 1 AND e.stock > 0 AND c.category_id = 4 AND e.store_id = a.store_id
               ORDER BY e.total_sold DESC, e.updated_at DESC
               LIMIT 1)
```

It works

The result like this :

```
+----+----------+------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
| id | store_id | name       | total_sold | updated_at          | store_name |
+----+----------+------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
|  3 |        1 | product 3  |          3 | 2017-07-11 07:53:41 | store 1    |
|  8 |        3 | product 8  |          8 | 2017-07-11 12:53:41 | store 3    |
|  9 |        4 | product 9  |          9 | 2017-07-11 13:53:41 | store 4    |
| 10 |        5 | product 10 |          0 | 2017-07-11 14:53:41 | store 5    |
| 11 |        6 | product 11 |          1 | 2017-07-11 15:53:41 | store 6    |
| 12 |        7 | product 12 |          2 | 2017-07-11 16:53:41 | store 7    |
| 14 |        8 | product 14 |          4 | 2017-07-11 18:53:41 | store 8    |
| 16 |        2 | product 16 |          6 | 2017-07-11 20:53:41 | store 2    |
+----+----------+------------+------------+---------------------+------------+
```

But seems my query is too long and maybe less fast

Is there a better solution to make the query faster and shorter?

**Update** :

I provide sample data below, and sqlfiddle of same: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3324a0/4

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stores` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `stores` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
  ('1', 'store 1'),
  ('2', 'store 2'),
  ('3', 'store 3'),
  ('4', 'store 4'),
  ('5', 'store 5'),
  ('6', 'store 6'),
  ('7', 'store 7'),
  ('8', 'store 8'),
  ('9', 'store 9'),
  ('10', 'store 10');



  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `store_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(70) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `total_sold` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `stock` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `products_store_id_foreign` (`store_id`),
  KEY `products_name_index` (`name`),
  CONSTRAINT `products_store_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `stores` (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `store_id`, `name`, `total_sold`, `stock`, `status`, `updated_at`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'product 1', '1', '1', '1', '2017-07-11 05:53:41'),
  ('2', '1', 'product 2', '2', '1', '1', '2017-07-11 06:53:41'),
  ('3', '1', 'product 3', '3', '1', '1', '2017-07-11 07:53:41'),
  ('4', '2', 'product 4', '4', '1', '1', '2017-07-11 08:53:41'),
  ('5', '2', 'product 5', '5', '1', '1', '2017-07-11 09:53:41'),
  ('6', '3', 'product 6', '6', '1', '1', '2017-07-11 10:53:41'),
  ('7', '3', 'product 7', '7', '1', '1', '2017-07-11 11:53:41'),
  ('8', '3', 'product 8', '8', '1', '1', '2017-07-11 12:53:41'),
  ('9', '4', 'product 9', '9', '1', '1', '2017-07-11 13:53:41'),
  ('10', '5', 'product 10', '0', '1', '1', '2017-07-11 14:53:41'),
  ('11', '6', 'product 11', '1', '1', '1', '2017-07-11 15:53:41'),
  ('12', '7', 'product 12', '2', '1', '1', '2017-07-11 16:53:41'),
  ('13', '8', 'product 13', '3', '1', '1', '2017-07-11 17:53:41'),
  ('14', '8', 'product 14', '4', '1', '1', '2017-07-11 18:53:41'),
  ('15', '2', 'product 15', '5', '1', '1', '2017-07-11 19:53:41'),
  ('16', '2', 'product 16', '6', '1', '1', '2017-07-11 20:53:41'),
  ('17', '3', 'product 17', '7', '1', '1', '2017-07-11 21:53:41');


  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
  ('1', 'category 1'),
  ('2', 'category 2'),
  ('3', 'category 3'),
  ('4', 'category 4');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products_categories` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `products_categories_product_id_foreign` (`product_id`),
  KEY `products_categories_category_id_foreign` (`category_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `products_categories_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `products_categories_product_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `products_categories` (`id`, `product_id`, `category_id`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', '4'),
  ('2', '2', '4'),
  ('3', '3', '4'),
  ('4', '4', '4'),
  ('5', '5', '4'),
  ('6', '6', '4'),
  ('7', '7', '4'),
  ('8', '8', '4'),
  ('9', '9', '4'),
  ('10', '10', '4'),
  ('11', '11', '4'),
  ('12', '12', '4'),
  ('13', '13', '4'),
  ('14', '14', '4'),
  ('15', '15', '4'),
  ('16', '16', '4'),
  ('17', '17', '4');
```

You can try right there and maybe help me make a shorter and faster query :)

Comment: A date filter in your subquery might help.

Comment: The join to store in the sub query seems unnecessary since you have store_id in products, the join to products_categories in the main query seems unnecessary since you have already done this in the sub query and the  a.status = 1 AND a.stock > 0 AND c.category_id = 4 portion of the where in the main query seems unnecessary since you have done this in the sub query.

Comment: @SuccessMan As explained, the data set is not representative of the problem. Also, refer to my original comment. Obviously, name and store name are irrelevant, so can be omitted.

Comment: @Strawberry I think the op wants the best selling product per store and if there is a draw the one with the most recent updated date (hence the ORDER BY e.total_sold DESC, e.updated_at DESC
               LIMIT 1 in the sub query)  - this is not the same as the product with the most recent updated date per store.

Comment: @SuccessMan its too much work for me to generate test data or transcribe yours if you want to provide sample data as text either in your question or sqlfiddle then I'll be happy to look at again.

Comment: @P.Salmon You may well be right. It's just that the data set provided fails to do the simple job of clarifying that. Plus, I don't think it much of a stretch to provide the data in the manner I've suggested. But it's for others to decide if they want to answer questions of this quality.

Comment: @P.Salmon, Okay. Look at this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3324a0/4

Comment: @Strawberry, You can see here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3324a0/4. I created a sample data. You can try it right there

Comment: @P.Salmon, I try follow your step and seems it works. Look at this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3324a0/9. How do you think?

Comment: I think strawberry's  answer is likely to be the fastest (and how I would have approached the problem if he hadn't beaten me to it) and you should run some timings to prove it. It really up to you which code you implement - the one you understand now which may be slower or the code you will come to understand and which is probably quicker.

Comment: @P.Salmon, Strawberry's answer is faster. But he has not used a join like my case. If the query using a join, it looks longer and very complex

Comment: You just need to add e
                JOIN products_categories c ON c.product_id = e.id
             WHERE e.status = 1 AND e.stock > 0 AND c.category_id = 4 after the FROM products in the y sub query. Keep biting the elephant it'll get to look less complex with experience.

Comment: @P.Salmon, Okay. I try like this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3324a0/13. Like that?

Comment: Not quite you should (almost) always include all the selected items other than the aggregations in group by so the y sub query should be GROUP BY m.store_id,n.name, o.category_id and the outer should be GROUP BY store_id,store_name, category_id, total_sold.

Comment: @P.Salmon, Look at this my update : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3324a0/16. Like that?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM products a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.store_id
            , x.total_sold
            , MAX(x.updated_at) updated_at 
         FROM products x 
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT store_id
                   , MAX(total_sold) total_sold 
                FROM products 
               GROUP 
                  BY store_id
            ) y 
           ON y.store_id = x.store_id 
          AND y.total_sold = x.total_sold 
        GROUP 
           BY store_id
            , total_sold
     ) b 
    ON b.store_id = a.store_id 
   AND b.total_sold = a.total_sold 
   AND b.updated_at = a.updated_at;
+----+----------+------------+------------+-------+--------+---------------------+
| id | store_id | name       | total_sold | stock | status | updated_at          |
+----+----------+------------+------------+-------+--------+---------------------+
|  3 |        1 | product 3  |          3 |     1 |      1 | 2017-07-11 07:53:41 |
| 16 |        2 | product 16 |          6 |     1 |      1 | 2017-07-11 20:53:41 |
|  8 |        3 | product 8  |          8 |     1 |      1 | 2017-07-11 12:53:41 |
|  9 |        4 | product 9  |          9 |     1 |      1 | 2017-07-11 13:53:41 |
| 10 |        5 | product 10 |          0 |     1 |      1 | 2017-07-11 14:53:41 |
| 11 |        6 | product 11 |          1 |     1 |      1 | 2017-07-11 15:53:41 |
| 12 |        7 | product 12 |          2 |     1 |      1 | 2017-07-11 16:53:41 |
| 14 |        8 | product 14 |          4 |     1 |      1 | 2017-07-11 18:53:41 |
+----+----------+------------+------------+-------+--------+---------------------+
8 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks. But why there is no join to products_categories table? Other than that there is also no condition this : `WHERE a.status = 1 AND a.stock > 0 AND c.category_id = 4`

Comment: @SuccessMan because I couldn't see the point of writing the trivial bits

Comment: What do you mean? But I've given sample data in sqlfiddle. Should have explained my point

Comment: You explained the point. But I know you can figure out how to solve the rest of the problem without my assistance.

Comment: I try like this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3324a0/16. What do you thing? Is that correct? I need confirmation from you. Because you are mysql master :)

Comment: @SuccessMan It's your data model, so it's for you to confirm but I would expect status, stock, and category_id to reappear as join conditions as you move further back up the query (so, yes, more joins I'm afraid). If you provided a more comprehensive data set, eliminating potential ambiguities, then I might be able to provide a more definitive answer.

Comment: I have checked it and it has worked. What do you mean by `a more comprehensive data set, eliminating potential ambiguities`. What do you mean I have to include all of my table schema and original data?